# Bootstrap for ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I installed a npm package bootstrap@4.1.0 for ReactJS portfolio App , but getting an error that non-JS module files deprecated.
So should I stop thinking of using Bootstrap for React app?

> crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

This is my package.json:

```
  "name": "react-scripts",
  "version": "4.0.3",
  "description": "Configuration and scripts for Create React App.",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app.git",
    "directory": "packages/react-scripts"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^10.12.0 || >=12.0.0"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues"
  },
  "files": [
    "bin",
    "config",
    "lib",
    "scripts",
    "template",
    "template-typescript",
    "utils"
  ],
  "bin": {
    "react-scripts": "./bin/react-scripts.js"
  },
  "types": "./lib/react-app.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.3",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "0.4.3",
    "@svgr/webpack": "5.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.7",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.0",
    "bfj": "^7.0.2",
    "camelcase": "^6.1.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "css-loader": "4.3.0",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^3.9.2",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.5.2",
    "file-loader": "6.1.1",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.5.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "26.6.0",
    "jest-circus": "26.6.0",
    "jest-resolve": "26.6.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.6.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.11.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.4",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.6.4",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.2.1",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "5.0.2",
    "prompts": "2.4.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^11.0.3",
    "react-refresh": "^0.8.3",
    "resolve": "1.18.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.5",
    "semver": "7.3.2",
    "style-loader": "1.3.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "4.2.3",
    "ts-pnp": "1.2.0",
    "url-loader": "4.1.1",
    "webpack": "4.44.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "5.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">= 16",
    "typescript": "^3.2.1 || ^4"
  },
  "peerDependenciesMeta": {
    "typescript": {
      "optional": true
    }
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "gitHead": "f92c37a6e6636ed1650ffd976c6881f59b1be803"
}
```

This is my webpack.config.js:

````
``` {
          test: cssRegex,
          exclude: cssModuleRegex,
          use: getStyleLoaders({
            importLoaders: 1,
            modules:true,
           
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction
              ? shouldUseSourceMap
              : isEnvDevelopment,
          }),
          // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
          // containing package claims to have no side effects.
          // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
          // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
          sideEffects: true,
        },```
````

Hope I have shared it correctly:)

Comment: I even tried installing bootstrap v5.

Comment: can you share what's in your package.json and webpack config?

Comment: @sculs Yeah.I did it , but could u please tell me whether I have shared the right code :(

Comment: It doesn't look it was installed. can you try running `npm install --save bootstrap` then also add this import to your `src/index.js` since you are using CRA

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'`